# Why is this code concatenating the empty string and an integer?

Tags: java

What does this snippet of code mean?

```
int value;
if (value > 0)
 String input = "" + value;
```

Comment: It's a rather grim way of getting the compiler to automatically convert an `int` into a `String`.

Comment: That's a lot of code for one line that needs explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is converting `value` to a string.  `"" + value` is very similar to `value.toString()`.  The `""` means the compiler is looking for a string after the `+`, so when it sees `value` in that space, it automatically calls `value.toString()` to produce the string result.

Comment: More like `Integer.toString(value)`, since it's an `int`, but the idea is the same (+1).

Comment: Using '`+`' with strings is a quite bad practice. The developer should use `value.toString()` or a `StringBuilder` (at least).

Comment: @air-dex That depends on the context. In a loop for example it could be considered bad practice, but for a one-time concatenation it is generally fine. Of course in this specific case the `Integer.toString()` approach is to be preferred.

Comment: @air-dex not necessarily on the StringBuilder.  The compiler automatically converts inline concatenations into the StringBuilder approach, but the concatenation approach is more readable.  The StringBuilder should only be used if the concatenation is occurring, for instance, in a loop, where the StringBuilder would need to be declared before the loop instead of inline as the compiler does.

Answer (score 2):

`String input = "" + value;` `value` is an integer type. adding it to empty string-`""` just making it a  string. Suppose `value = 3`, then `""+value` will be `"3"`

**Edit**: Forgot to mention about [`String.valueOf(val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) function, another static utility method to convert almost all primitive type to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler know how to add an integer with some string value. So in the code rather calling directly the integer to string conversion method. The coder generates an constant string ""(having no value in it) and then call concatenation operator(+) overloaded method to add and cast the integer into string value.